# VBox - shared folder stopped working

Tags: server, mount, virtualbox

On my Win7 host I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 guest running. I installed the guest additions and successfully mounted the shared folder. I also configured ubuntu to auto mount the shared folder on startup. This was working for the last 2 weeks (with many restarts, never had a problem) but out of nowhere it stopped working with error "No such device". I am not able to mount the shared folder anymore. Only thing I can think of which COULD be a reason is that I switched the network configuration of the VM from NAT to Bridged Network.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that a kernel update has disabled the vbox guest additions? Do you tried reinstalling the guest additions?

Comment: I dont know how to update the kernel so how can this happen? With "apt-get update" or "apt-get upgrade"? I havent played around with any system applications only with apache2 and tomcat.

Comment: Yes, you get kernel updates with the regular system updates "apt-get update".   Just try to run the "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" script again.

Comment: Nope, no luck with re-doing the whole preparing and installing thing of the Guest Additions ....